# how can i download 200+ millions records from teradata using bteq?

Tags: teradata, large-data, bteq

Using below statement I am able to download 1 million records. But not getting how can i download 200+ millions records from the teradata table into pipe separated text file.

Below is the code that I am currently using.

```
.export reset

.set width 1048575

.SET RECORDMODE OFF

.SET FORMAT OFF

.SET SEPARATOR "|"

.export report file=test_file.txt

select * from test_schema.test_table
```

I found this [link](https://tekslate.com/bteq-features-teradata) and understood that teradata could have some limitation on this.
But I am sure there must be some other ways to download this large data set. Can you please share some examples on how can i do that?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use bteq, or you can use Fast Export/TPT.  There's tons of info out there on all of these.

Comment: You *could* use BTEQ but likely *should* use TPT Export for something that size. BTW - default for BTEQ is actually "no limit" and if you did want to impose a RETLIMIT the max allowed would be (2^64)-1.